# how to get data through document.getElementById in script

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have written a statement like this in java program

```
(function() { return (document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0].innerHTML); })();
```

in this the line

```
document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0].innerHTML
```

returns the data with class name ="two" i have another class in the same html page with same class name. i want that data also to be returned. how to modify this code ,plz help me

for example i have written 
 code  like this

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="one">
        welcome
        <div class="two">
            hello world
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            bye world
        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">
  Click</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName('two');
            var mapped = [].map.call(x, function(el) {
                return el.innerHTML;
            });
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = mapped.join(',');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

how to embed this functionality in my code i.e in this code

```
  (function() { return (document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0].innerHTML); })();
```

Comment: `(function() { myFunction(); })();` ?

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To access other elements with the same class name you can just change the index of the `getElementsByClassName()`. If you want to return both elements (all the elements in this case), you can loop through them and return them inside of a string array:

```
function myFunction() {
    var twos = [];
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("two");

    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        twos.push(elements[i].innerHTML);
    }

    return twos;
}
```

And then you can access the elements by the index:

```
var foo = myFunction();
console.log(foo[0]);  // 'hello world'
console.log(foo[1]);  // 'bye world'
```